# Fancy splitting in gnus based on subject of message

Tags: gnus

I'm trying to write fancy split that puts any message with "[foobar]" in the subject into a specific folder but nothing seems to work.

I have:

```
(setq nnimap-split-fancy '(|("subject" "\\[foobar\\]" "INBOX.foobar")
                          (...)) 
                          "default")
```

but it still ends up in the "default" mailbox.

If I change the regexp to just "foobar" it works (but then it matches other messages I don't want included). I think it's something to do with the escaping of the brackets. I've tried a couple of different of variations of escaping but there's something I'm missing. Or maybe I'm not fancy enough.

Comment: Did you set `nnmail-split-methods` to `nnmail-split-fancy`?

Comment: Tassilo Horn: Yep. It works if I do just "foobar" or "f.*bar". I just  can't seem to escape the brackets properly.

Comment: That's strange. Given that this is a regular expression, they are in fact quoted correctly...

Comment: Maybe gnus is doing something to the subject with the brackets at the beginning?

Comment: I don't know. You could figure out which function evaluates the fancy splits and edebug it in order to see what's happening exactly.

Comment: Thanks your replies Tassilo. Finally figured it out. Had to use "\\\[foobar]".  `rx` to the rescue.

Answer (score 1):

Finally figured this out.

Had to use:

```
(setq nnimap-split-fancy '(|("subject" "\\[foobar]" "INBOX.foobar")
                      (...)) 
                      "default")
```

Comment: Please accept your own answer so that the robots don't keep placing this question periodically on the Active list.